# Cache hit ratio effect on performance

Tags: performance, math, caching, system

I'm currently reading the second edition of Systems Performance by Brendan Gregg and had a question on the section about caching in Chapter 2. This section defines cache hit ratio as

```
hit ratio = hits / (hits + misses)
```

It goes on to say that the relationship between cache hit ratio and "performance" (for some hypothetical measure of system performance) is nonlinear. Specifically,

> The performance difference between 98% and 99% is much greater than that between 10% and 11%. This is a nonlinear profile because of the difference in speed between cache hits and misses - the two storage tiers at play. The greater the difference, the steeper the slope becomes.

I don't quite understand where the nonlinearity in this relationship originates from. In order to explain this to myself, I concocted the following example. Consider the following, we model performance by some function `f`, where a lower value of `f` denotes better performance.

```
f(hit) = 10
f(miss) = 100
```

i.e. misses are 10x more expensive than hits. Assuming a hit ratio of 0, the "expected" performance of this system will be `(0*10) + (1*100) = 100`. A hit ratio of .01 (1% hits) yields `(.01*10)+(.99*100) = 99.1`. Finally a hit ratio of .02 (2% hits) yields `(.02*10) + (.98*100) = 98.2`. AFAICT, this is a linear relationship. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question after reading the same book, and now that I have answered my question, so I will answer it.

Performance is nonlinear with hit rate because execution time and performance are different things.

As you wrote, equations with `f` (eg. `(0*10) + (1*100) = 100`) is linear in the hit ratio.
However, it does not actually represent performance, but average execution time.
Performance is relative, and when comparing two performances, we use the ratio of the **inverse of the execution time**.

This inverse is the source of the seemingly linear but actually nonlinear behavior.

I'm a non-native English speaker, so sorry if it's hard to read.
I hope my answer helps you.